# Eclipse: maintain multiple product_configuration and their dependencies

Tags: eclipse, configuration, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, product

I have an Eclipse-RCP project with multiple product_configuration.product files.

They are sort of siblings; product-B has all product-A's dependencies but have different launching/configuration.

The problem comes when I add a new plug-in to product-A (which I launch the most often), and then forgot to add the plug-in to product B,C,D etc.

It stays hidden until I actually launch/export the other configuration; only then I see it's missing and it's a bit painful.

Is there any way to solve this without manually adding plug-in dependencies into each product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a Feature based configuration rather than just plugins. Then you can have one or more common features used by all of the products and other features containing the plugins unique to each product.

Some more on features [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseFeatureProject/article.html)